# Changing levels of inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it fine to change the acess levels of inherited class like the way we want them?

```
class Base {

public:
   size_t x;

protected:
   size_t y;
};


class Derived : private Base {

protected:
   size_t x;

public:
   size_t y;
};
```

Does the `Base` class inherits only the private members or all the members of `Base` will be `private` by default? I tried to interchange the access levels but i don't understand what am i doing here?

Comment: You mean "the `Derived` class inherits ..."

Answer (score 3):

No, `Derived` can't suddenly decide that it's going to steal the ability to read a member that's `private` in `Base`.

What you're actually doing is creating entirely *different* variables in `Derived`, which happen to have the same name.

Comment: [...] and hide the base class variables.

Comment: @Xeo: Yes, indeed. Thought I'd leave that detail for another day, as it's not directly relevant here and the OP — now knowing that this approach is not what he wants — will not be diving into his attempt any further where he'd discover name hiding as an issue.

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you inherit from `Base` with `private` modifier is that only the `Derived` class has access to `Base`'s members. If you decide to create a `AnotherDerived` that inherits from `Derived`, you won't be able to access any of `Base`'s members.

Check this [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/115-inheritance-and-access-specifiers/) for more information on inheritance and access specifiers.